# SOA (Structure of array) vs AOS (Array of Structure)

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm studying the difference between SOA and AOS but I want to know other details.

I have only this info [image]

During the course, we see this example but didn't go into the depth of these two type of implementations, sorry if isn't clear my question
[image: example2]

But I want to know the main difference between them and an example to understand better.

Comment: The difference and an example is literally in your second screenshot.

Comment: I know, but maybe a explanation in details because we only see the image without depth discussion

Comment: The code seems to be written for C, not for C++.

Comment: @user17732522 I've  edit, thanks

Comment: Suppose that what you want to do with your SOA or AOS is plot some data.  Suppose you've got a nice plotting function that's declared as `void plot(float data[], int npoints)`.  Now suppose you've got an AOS.  How can you pass all your `x` points to `plot()`?

Comment: I should create something like that in my example and declared the points inside it, right? So in this way I have all my data points for the calculations

Comment: In this way I'll have all my data in a contiguous memory locations and I'll have less latency and better performance? Sorry for the second comment but I'm thiking about your propose

Comment: I'm not saying you should use one of the other.  Personally, I would always use an array of structures, and I would never use a bunch of parallel arrays.  But the plot-the-data example is one way to understand the difference.  It's not one of "latency" or "performance", it's just that — in my example — plotting the data might require temporarily copying it all to a second, contiguous array, which is a plain nuisance for the programmer, regardless of what it does to the program's performance.

Answer (score 0):

The first image is THE difference.

If you want to store N objects where each consists of M sub-objects, you have two basic choices how to do that:

- One array of length `N` with each element being whole object - i.e. an array of structs.
- `M` arrays (held in a struct), each of length `N` and each storing only one sub-object. The object is thus scattered across `M` arrays - i.e. struct of arrays.

Comment: So, with the SOA which are the advantages and with AOS? Sorry if you don't understand my question

Comment: @FeliceCoppola Advantages and disadvantages are literally on your first picture.

Comment: @273K True, sorry but I'm very confused because I'm studying too stuffs, I need to rewatch my notes. Thanks

Comment: @FeliceCoppola The core idea is to use structures matching the access patterns in the application, ideally you want a sequential memory access aligned to cache lines. If you need to iterate over a particular sub-object of all objects, AoS will be better. If you need to process an object as whole, accessing all of its sub-objects, SoA might be a better fit. Of course one should always measure.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the advantage of "structure of arrays", let's look at the example code. The original piece is:

```
    for(i=0; i<1024; i++) {
        float x = points[i].x;
        float y = points[i].y;
        float z = points[i].z;
        float d = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        dist[i] = d;
    }
```

When converting this into assembly language complex expressions need to be broken down into instructions; so it'll actually end up something more like:

```
    for(i=0; i<1024; i++) {
        float x = points[i].x;
        float y = points[i].y;
        float z = points[i].z;
        float tempx = x*x;
        float tempy = y*y;
        float tempz = z*z;
        float tempxy = tempx + tempy;
        float tempxyz = tempxy + tempz;
        float d = sqrt(tempxyz);
        dist[i] = d;
    }
```

For "structure of arrays" the compiler can convert it into something more like:

```
    for(i=0; i<1024; i += 4) {
        float x1 = points.x[i];
        float x2 = points.x[i+1];
        float x3 = points.x[i+2];
        float x4 = points.x[i+3];

        float y1 = points.y[i];
        float y2 = points.y[i+1];
        float y3 = points.y[i+2];
        float y4 = points.y[i+3];

        float z1 = points.z[i];
        float z2 = points.z[i+1];
        float z3 = points.z[i+2];
        float z4 = points.z[i+3];

        float tempx1 = x1*x1;
        float tempx2 = x2*x2;
        float tempx3 = x3*x3;
        float tempx4 = x4*x4;

        float tempy1 = y1*y1;
        float tempy2 = y2*y2;
        float tempy3 = y3*y3;
        float tempy4 = y4*y4;

        float tempz1 = z1*z1;
        float tempz2 = z2*z2;
        float tempz3 = z3*z3;
        float tempz4 = z4*z4;

        float tempxy1 = tempx1 + tempy1;
        float tempxy2 = tempx2 + tempy2;
        float tempxy3 = tempx3 + tempy3;
        float tempxy4 = tempx4 + tempy4;

        float tempxyz1 = tempxy1 + tempz1;
        float tempxyz2 = tempxy2 + tempz2;
        float tempxyz3 = tempxy3 + tempz3;
        float tempxyz4 = tempxy4 + tempz4;

        float d1 = sqrt(tempxyz1);
        float d2 = sqrt(tempxyz2);
        float d3 = sqrt(tempxyz3);
        float d4 = sqrt(tempxyz4);

        dist[i] = d1;
        dist[i+1] = d2;
        dist[i+2] = d3;
        dist[i+3] = d4;
    }
```

Now; a lot of modern CPUs support SIMD, where a single instruction is able to do the same operation on multiple pieces of data in parallel in the same amount of time that it would've taken to do one operation on one piece of data.

Let's rearrange the previous version so that everything that can be done in parallel with a single SIMD instruction is on the same line:

```
    for(i=0; i<1024; i += 4) {

        float x1 = points.x[i]; float x2 = points.x[i+1]; float x3 = points.x[i+2]; float x4 = points.x[i+3];

        float y1 = points.y[i]; float y2 = points.y[i+1]; float y3 = points.y[i+2]; float y4 = points.y[i+3];

        float z1 = points.z[i]; float z2 = points.z[i+1]; float z3 = points.z[i+2]; float z4 = points.z[i+3];

        float tempx1 = x1*x1; float tempx2 = x2*x2; float tempx3 = x3*x3; float tempx4 = x4*x4;

        float tempy1 = y1*y1; float tempy2 = y2*y2; float tempy3 = y3*y3; float tempy4 = y4*y4;

        float tempz1 = z1*z1; float tempz2 = z2*z2; float tempz3 = z3*z3; float tempz4 = z4*z4;

        float tempxy1 = tempx1 + tempy1; float tempxy2 = tempx2 + tempy2; float tempxy3 = tempx3 + tempy3; float tempxy4 = tempx4 + tempy4;

        float tempxyz1 = tempxy1 + tempz1; float tempxyz2 = tempxy2 + tempz2; float tempxyz3 = tempxy3 + tempz3; float tempxyz4 = tempxy4 + tempz4;

        float d1 = sqrt(tempxyz1);
        float d2 = sqrt(tempxyz2);
        float d3 = sqrt(tempxyz3);
        float d4 = sqrt(tempxyz4);

        dist[i] = d1; dist[i+1] = d2; dist[i+2] = d3; dist[i+3] = d4;
    }
```

If you compare this to the original (or compare it to "array of structures") you can see that most instructions are now doing 4 times as much work. If all instructions were doing 4 times as much work it'd be 4 times faster. Unfortunately, for this example code, the `sqrt()` is probably going to ruin most of the benefits (it might only be 10% faster).

However; that "4 times as much" (and the "up to 4 times faster") depends on the SIMD size (how many pieces of data a single instruction can operate on in parallel), and I mostly chose "4 times" because I'm too lazy to do a lot of extra typing.

On modern real computers the SIMD size is often 128-bits or more (up to 512 bits for AVX-512 on 80x86, and up to 2048-bits for SVE2 on a few extremely rare niche ARM systems). A `float` is typically 32 bits, so with "128-bit SIMD" you'd have 4 floats per SIMD register, so it actually would be "4 times as much per instruction". With "256-bit SIMD" it would be "8 times as much per instruction", and with "512-bit SIMD" it would be "16 times as much per instruction".

Of course this is only CPUs. For GPUs the SIMD size is even larger; and if you combined "structure of arrays" with GPGPU the performance improvement (from SIMD) could be a lot more.

For disadvantages, "structure of arrays" is less convenient for programmers (especially in object oriented programming, where "array of objects" is a lot easier than "object of arrays"). This makes it a compromise between convenience and potential performance improvement (where the potential performance improvement depends on the nature of the data and what you intended to do with it).